# TensorFlow Lite on RISC V newlib

Tags: tensorflow, g++, tensorflow-lite, riscv, newlib

I'd like to compile TensorFlow Lite using the riscv64-unknown-elf (newlib) cross-compiler to run it on Spike or some other RISC-V simulator. AFAIK, no such option exists:

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/targets/riscv_makefile.inc
   It seems that support exists for riscv64-unknown-linux, and for riscv32-unknown-elf (is it as trivial as changing this one to riscv64-unknown-elf? I tried this and I'm getting errors on `make`)
2. https://edge.seas.harvard.edu/files/edge/files/carrv_workshop_submission_2019_camera_ready.pdf the authors of this paper successfully compiled TensorFlow Lite using the newlib compiler, but they mention that they had to make changes to the TFLite source code. The changes have not been shared to my knowledge.

Comment: I try the same but still can't reach the goal (